# CocoaPods intermediate files build failure with xcodebuild

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, cocoapods, xcodebuild, libtool

I'm trying to get xcodebuild working with a CocoaPods project and have run into an issue. I'm running:

```
xcodebuild -workspace 'MyWorkspace.xcworkspace' -scheme DefaultScheme -configuration Release CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="Distribution Profile" PRODUCT_NAME="MyProduct"
```

I get the following errors:

```
The following build commands failed:
    Libtool /Users/myuser/repos/MyProjectDir/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Pods.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/libsupport.a normal armv7s
    Libtool /Users/myuser/repos/MyProjectDir/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Pods.build/Objects-normal/arm64/libsupport.a normal arm64
    Libtool /Users/myuser/repos/MyProjectDir/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Pods.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libsupport.a normal armv7
```

The builds work fine in xcode. I've googled this to death and have yet to find a solution. Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: I also get two lines like the following for every pod.

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lPods-AFNetworking
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lPods-AFNetworking is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
```

Second Edit: It works perfectly if I leave out the PRODUCT_NAME argument. What's up with that?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out, `xcodebuild` did not like the `PRODUCT_NAME` argument to be last. I deleted the argument altogether and everything built. Then I moved the `PRODUCT_NAME` to before `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` and it worked. So, I thought it might have built the second time because the pods resources were built and living in the derived data folder. To check that out, I blew away the derived data and built again (with the `PRODUCT_NAME` argument last) and it built just fine.

Honestly, I'm not sure what the heck the problem was. Perhaps this will help someone out in the future. If anyone has a real solution, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `xcodebuild` is one the worst documented tools I've ever worked with. Possibly the mentioned character was the issue but never know :/ What I can add is that in general You should avoid passing arguments such as `PRODUCT_NAME` via command line. It's much better to create multiple configurations and just switch them while building artifacts. From my experience I know that these arguments cause strange behavior sometimes.